# Async axios dont run promise using NODEJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, promise, axios

I'm developing a multiplayer game using *vue* at client side and *nojejs* as game server (I'm using `vue-sockets.io` to communicate clients and server).
when I create the game instance on the node side, it will have tiles and hidden (both arrays of images coming from an api). For this is used the axios, the problem is that the created game is returned to the client before running the axios. So the client will get the game without the images.

```
createGame(playerName, socketID, boardSize) {
    this.contadorID = this.contadorID+1;

        var game = new MemoryGame(this.contadorID, playerName, boardSize);

        new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            console.log("a");
            game.getTiles().then(response=>{
                console.log("getTiles");
        game.tiles = game.getRandomNPieces(response.data.data, game.board.length/2);
                console.log(game.tiles);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
            console.log('=>' + game.tiles);
        }).then(function(result) { // (***)
            console.log("b");
          game.getHidden().then(response=>{
        game.hidden = game.getRandomHidden(response.data.data);
      }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    game.player1SocketID = socketID;
    this.games.set(game.gameID, game);
    return game;
}
```

[image: Print with logs]

The program never reaches the second axios call.
The gameList log comes from the game that is returned to the user.

Game instance in client 1 (who created the game): 
[image: Game instance in client 1 (who created the game)]

Game instance in client 2 (the game is in lobby and already have the tiles):
[image: Game instance in client 2 (the game is in lobby and already have the tiles)]

Comment: In order to help you efficiently, you need to paste the relevant portions of your code as text into the question and format them as code.  Then, we can copy/paste portions of that and correct it.  Code should NOT only be available as an external link to an image.  It should be pasted INTO your question as text.  These are the rules/guidelines of stack overflow.  There are many things wrong with your code, but I'm not going to manually retype all your code from an image in order to show you how to fix it.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks for your advice! I'll past my code here!

Comment: I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do as you have async operations, but are attempting to synchronously return a `game` object that has not yet been operated on, but the first core problem is has is that you create `new Promise()` but you never call `resolve()` or `reject()` to resolve or reject that promise.  What you show is a promise anti-pattern.  There is no need to wrap an existing promise from `getTiles()` in another promise.  You can just use the promise that it returns.  There are lots of problems with this code.  Not sure what the objective of it is.

Comment: @jfriend00 before this i'm only using the axios, but the problem here is: the method return the game instance to the client and then he runs the axios code. So, the client will get the game without the images.
Now i tried to use the resolve() and my code now reaches both axios call, but only after returning the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `createGame()` appears to rely on some asynchronous operations to initialize the game properly, you cannot just synchronously return a finished game object from `createGame()`.  As you've already observed, `createGame()` will return the game object before any of the async operations have completed.  So, instead, what you need to do is you need to return a promise whose resolved value is the game object and then you need to chain all the async operations together properly so your main promise will be resolved when the game object is all done.  Here's one way to structure that:

```
createGame(playerName, socketID, boardSize) {
    this.contadorID = this.contadorID+1;

    var game = new MemoryGame(this.contadorID, playerName, boardSize);

    console.log("a");
    return game.getTiles().then(response=> {
        console.log("getTiles");
        game.tiles = game.getRandomNPieces(response.data.data, game.board.length/2);
        console.log(game.tiles);
        console.log('=>' + game.tiles);
        console.log("b");
        // return nested promise so it chains into main promise chain
        return game.getHidden().then(response=>{
            game.hidden = game.getRandomHidden(response.data.data);
        });
    }).then(() => {
        // finish initializing game object and 
        // make it be the resolved value of the returned promise
        game.player1SocketID = socketID;
        this.games.set(game.gameID, game);
        return game;
    }).catch(function (error) {
        // log error and rethrow so promise stays rejected
        // this will log for any of our rejected promises since they are chained
        console.log(error);
        throw error;
    });
}
```

And, this changes `createGame()` to return a promise so you have to change the way you use it like this:

```
someObj.createGame(...).then(game => {
    // game object is ready to use here
}).catch(err => {
    // error creating game object
});
```